# SIFR: How much is too much?

Tags: sifr

First time poster here, using the "`sifr3-r436`" build.

I am doing work on my company's website and decided it was time for us to start employing some SIFR technology. So far, I have been able to figure it out quite easily, with the exception of a question or two. Basically, I have two burning questions that I would like answered.

1) How much SIFR is considered "ok"? Although I am only using SIFR for headlines, per the recommendations in the FAQ/Walk-through, I still have a substantial amount of text that I would like to convert to SIFR. Please view [the website](http://www.holidayvacations.net/test) to get an idea of how much SIFR I'm using (Rockwell font headlines and subheads). Is this too much?

2) How do I control font color with SIFR? Obviously I know you can set it inside the '`sifr-config.js`' file. However, I have many different colored headlines that I would like to use.. I'm currently doing it this way:

```
sIFR.replace(rockwell, {
selector: '.h3_sifr', css: '.sIFR-root { font-size: 18px; background-color: #a63f03; color: #bf7e04;}', forceSingleLine: true, wmode: 'transparent', tuneHeight: -5,
});
sIFR.replace(rockwell, {
selector: '.h3_sifr_green', css: '.sIFR-root { font-size: 18px; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #597704;}', forceSingleLine: true, wmode: 'transparent', tuneHeight: -5,
});
sIFR.replace(rockwell, {
selector: '.h3_sifr_maroon', css: '.sIFR-root { font-size: 18px; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #330000;}', forceSingleLine: true, wmode: 'transparent', tuneHeight: -5,
});
sIFR.replace(rockwell, {
selector: '.h3_sifr_blue', css: '.sIFR-root { font-size: 18px; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #005995;}', forceSingleLine: true, wmode: 'transparent', tuneHeight: -5,
});
sIFR.replace(rockwell, {
selector: '.h3_sifr_cruise', css: '.sIFR-root { font-size: 18px; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #016EA1;}', forceSingleLine: true, wmode: 'transparent', tuneHeight: -5,
});
sIFR.replace(rockwell, {
selector: '.h3_sifr_australia', css: '.sIFR-root { font-size: 18px; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #277c5d;}', forceSingleLine: true, wmode: 'transparent', tuneHeight: -5,
});
sIFR.replace(rockwell, {
selector: '.h3_sifr_intl', css: '.sIFR-root { font-size: 18px; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #1b2f15;}', forceSingleLine: true, wmode: 'transparent', tuneHeight: -5,
});
sIFR.replace(rockwell, {
selector: '.h3_sifr_us', css: '.sIFR-root { font-size: 18px; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #32588b;}', forceSingleLine: true, wmode: 'transparent', tuneHeight: -5,
});
sIFR.replace(rockwell, {
selector: '.h3_sifr_hawaii', css: '.sIFR-root { font-size: 18px; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #4a1e52;}', forceSingleLine: true, wmode: 'transparent', tuneHeight: -5,
});
sIFR.replace(rockwell, {
selector: '.h3_sifr_rail', css: '.sIFR-root { font-size: 18px; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #304c2a;}', forceSingleLine: true, wmode: 'transparent', tuneHeight: -5,
});
sIFR.replace(rockwell, {
selector: '.h3_sifr_canada', css: '.sIFR-root { font-size: 18px; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #0a2754;}', forceSingleLine: true, wmode: 'transparent', tuneHeight: -5,
});
sIFR.replace(rockwell, {
selector: '.h3_sifr_alaska', css: '.sIFR-root { font-size: 18px; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #083c4b;}', forceSingleLine: true, wmode: 'transparent', tuneHeight: -5,
});
sIFR.replace(rockwell, {
selector: '.h3_sifr_sadc', css: '.sIFR-root { font-size: 18px; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #630002;}', forceSingleLine: true, wmode: 'transparent', tuneHeight: -5,
});
sIFR.replace(rockwell, {
selector: '.h3_sifr_easternus', css: '.sIFR-root { font-size: 18px; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #8b3100;}', forceSingleLine: true, wmode: 'transparent', tuneHeight: -5,
});
sIFR.replace(rockwell, {
selector: '.h3_sifr_lightgray', css: '.sIFR-root { font-size: 18px; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #999999;}', forceSingleLine: true, wmode: 'transparent', tuneHeight: -5,
});
sIFR.replace(rockwell, {
selector: '.h3_sifr_medgray', css: '.sIFR-root { font-size: 18px; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #666666;}', forceSingleLine: true, wmode: 'transparent', tuneHeight: -5,
});
sIFR.replace(rockwell, {
selector: '.h3_sifr_darkgray', css: '.sIFR-root { font-size: 18px; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #333333;}', forceSingleLine: true, wmode: 'transparent', tuneHeight: -5,
});
sIFR.replace(rockwell, {
selector: '.h3_sifr_extended', css: '.sIFR-root { font-size: 18px; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #175700;}', forceSingleLine: true, wmode: 'transparent', tuneHeight: -5,
});
sIFR.replace(rockwell, {
selector: '.h3_sifr_orange', css: '.sIFR-root { font-size: 18px; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #a63f03;}', forceSingleLine: true, wmode: 'transparent', tuneHeight: -5,
});
```

Now, as you can see, the only way I have been able to do the different colors is through a separate replace statement for each and every color. I tried changing the color 'inline' (i.e., `<span class="h3_sifr" style="color:#123456></span>`), but this does not work. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're using a bit too much sIFR. Try limiting it to just the main headers, and don't replace the links.

The CSS issue is a bit of a pickle, no easy answer there. You can copy the other shared properties to the `rockwell` object though, so you don't have to repeat those.

Also try to refrain from using transparency, and you shouldn't need to use `forceSingleLine` I think.

Comment: Im using forceSingleLine because the sifr text is dropping to a second line when it is being replaced.  I couldn't figure out how to fix this without using this property.  Any tips?

I will trim down my use of SIFR, my hunch was that I was probably using too much anyways.

Thanks for the response.

Comment: Probably the Flash font is wider than the HTML font, which causes trouble with your layout. Use `letter-spacing` in the `.sIFR-active *` styles to make the HTML text wider.